# Where is target specified in tensorflow's load_csv function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to follow along this tensorflow tutorial which uses a `load_csv` function.  [TUTORIAL_LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/tutorials/tflearn/index.html)

One of two lines in question is:

> ```
> IRIS_TEST = "iris_test.csv"
> test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(
>                                                    filename=IRIS_TEST,
>                                                    target_dtype=np.int
>                                                   )
> ```

Where `"iris_test.csv"` looks like:

```
30,4,setosa,versicolor,virginica
5.9,3.0,4.2,1.5,1
6.9,3.1,5.4,2.1,2
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,0
6.0,3.4,4.5,1.6,1
5.5,2.5,4.0,1.3,1
6.2,2.9,4.3,1.3,1
5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,0
6.3,2.8,5.1,1.5,2
5.6,3.0,4.1,1.3,1
6.7,2.5,5.8,1.8,2
7.1,3.0,5.9,2.1,2
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,0
```

I'm pretty sure the target of the machine learning exercise is the `verginica` column but I've no idea how it's specified as such.

Is it implied as the last column?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.9/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py):

```
def load_csv(filename, target_dtype, target_column=-1, has_header=True):
  """Load dataset from CSV file."""
```

default for `target_column` is `-1`.  So, last column, good to know.